# Discord dm bot that can dm back

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to make a donation bot, where in the channel when a person types `!donate` the bot will Dm them.

I got all that down but I am trying to make so that the person decides on how to donate like `!cashapp`, `!paypal`, etc., in the dms. It would send them that specific way to send money, for example once the bot Dms the use user what service they would like to pay with and the user says `!cashapp` it will send another message with my cashtag, or if they say `!paypal` it would send my paypal link.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@client.command()
async def donate(ctx, paymentMethod: str):
    if (paymentMethod.lower() == "paypal"):
        await ctx.send("PayPal link: ...")
    elif (paymentMethod.lower() == "cashapp"):
        await ctx.send("Cashapp Link: ...")
    else:
        await ctx.send("The provided payment method is not available.")
    
@donate.error
async def donate_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("Incorrect use of command!")

client.run("your bot token here")
```

Usage:
`!donate {payment method}` - Without the '`{}`'

Check the [`documentation`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `user.send` to send a message to the user dm and use it in the same way as `ctx.send` and `channel.send`.

```py
await ctx.author.send("paypal link: ...") # ctx.author is the member that call the command
```

And 2 command will have different function so you just need to write both of them in a different way.

If you planning to make it into 1 command you can use if else check

Answer (score 0):

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def steam(ctx):
if  ctx.author.send():
await ctx.send("you not boster")
else:
await ctx.author.send(random.choice(list(open('steam.txt'))))
i want if someone send a dm
its not Returns a dm
someone know how to do this?